# what is the best way to get a specific number from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have the folowing list :

```py
l = [
    'D111_26680270__2019_10.xml',
    'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.PDF',
    'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.xdp',
    'D111_32338396__2019_10.xml',
    'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.PDF',
    'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.xdp',
    'D111_40037513__2019_10_generat.pdf',
    'D111_31123410__2019_10.xml',
    'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.PDF',
    'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.xdp'
]
```

How do i get a list with only the number after `'D111_'` like `'26680270'` and `'40037513'` from all the examples in the list?
Thank you.

Comment: What if a file starts with `D112`? Is it always the 5th to 13th index? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `str.split` in a list comprehension

```
>>> data = ['D111_26680270__2019_10.xml', 'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.xdp', 'D111_32338396__2019_10.xml', 'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.xdp', 'D111_40037513__2019_10_generat.pdf', 'D111_31123410__2019_10.xml', 'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.xdp']
>>> [i.split('_')[1] for i in data]
['26680270', '26680270', '26680270', '32338396', '32338396', '32338396', '40037513', '31123410', '31123410', '31123410']
```

Comment: This is the easiest way. In case you need more complex finding, link not being always after `'D111_'` you may need to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As you have fixed number used slicing it's efficient and simple way

```py
>>> data = ['D111_26680270__2019_10.xml', 'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_26680270__2019_10_generat.xdp', 'D111_32338396__2019_10.xml', 'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_32338396__2019_10_generat.xdp', 'D111_40037513__2019_10_generat.pdf', 'D111_31123410__2019_10.xml', 'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.PDF', 'D111_31123410__2019_10_generat.xdp']

>>> [item[5:13] for item in data]
['26680270', '26680270', '26680270', '32338396', '32338396', '32338396', '40037513', '31123410', '31123410', '31123410']
```